# Primefaces dataTable, filter on localized enum values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable, enums

I have a `p:datatable` that is populated by a list of domain objects

Each domain object has a value that is tied to an `enum PrivateIndustry` : P, K or N , that corresponds to a database value.

these values are then presented in the `p:dataTable` via localization, `labels_LOCALE.properties` to make them human readable, with the `com.package.PrivateIndustry.P/K/N` syntax.

This works okay for readability, but when i Use `PF('dataTableId').filter()` to filter the dataTable, I cannot filter for the localized values, only the pure enum values (ie P, K or N)

ie:

```
    <p:column headerText="#{labels.header}"
         filterBy="#{domainobject.privateIndustry}" filterStyle="display: none"
         sortBy="#{domainobject.privateIndustry}" >
         <h:outputText value="#{domainobject.privateIndustry}"/>
    </p:column>
```

I can remedy this by populating the names in the domain object as String using `ResourceBundle.getString("com.package.PrivateIndustry...")` but this seems rather unneccesary and convoluted.

Can I parse `filterBy=""` with a better value, or make `PF().filter()` work on the client side data?

Comment: You can always implement custom filters... See the PF docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I solved the functionality in code rather than in xhtml:

upon creation of the domain objects, in the constructor,call a method that generates a String containing the parsed String from the enum value:

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class DomainObject   {
    private PrivateIndustry privateIndustry;
    private String enumStringValue;

    public void generateEnumStringValue() { 
        ResourceBundle rb= ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels",FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
        this.enumStringValue = rb.getString("com.package.DomainObject.PrivateIndustry." + privateIndustry.name());
    }
    public String getEnumStringValue() {
        return emumStringValue;
    }

    public enum PrivateIndustry {

        P("Private"),

        N("Industry"),

        K("Combined");
        private final String name;

        PrivateIndustry(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }      
    }
}
```

and then, in the bean:

```
public String getEnumStringValue(DomainObject domainObject) {

    return domainObject.getEnumStringValue();
}
```

and finally:

```
<p:column headerText="#{labels.header}"
          filterBy="#{backingBean.getEnumStringValue(domainObject)}"
          sortBy="#{backingBean.getEnumStringValue(domainObject)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{domainObject.privateIndustry}"/>

</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can manage all from the page xhtml, without touching your java beans:

```
<p:importEnum type="it.example.PrintRequestFormat" var="PrintRequestFormat" allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES" />
<p:column visible="true" filterBy="#{req.format.name()}" sortBy="#{req.format}" headerText="#{msg['pressroom_list.format']}" filterMatchMode="in">
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="#{msg['pressroom_list.format']}" onchange="PF('requestsTable').filter()" panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
            <f:selectItems value="#{PrintRequestFormat.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}" var="format" itemValue="#{req.format.name()}" itemLabel="#{msg['printrequest.format.'.concat(format)]}"/>
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['printrequest.format.'.concat(req.format)]}" />
</p:column>
```